# Uncaught RangeError : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given the following jQuery function.

```
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu>a", function(event) {

    $(this).closest("a").attr("href", "../public_resources/Category.jsf?id=5").trigger('click');
});
```

This function is called, when a `<span>` inside an `<li>` like as follows is clicked.

```
<li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent subMenu" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">

    <a href="../public_resources/Category.jsf?id=5" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-submenu-link ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="ui-menuitem-icon ui-icon ui-icon-contact"></span><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Occassion</span>
    </a>

</li>
```

As can be seen, the given jQuery function is mapped by a CSS class `subMenu` (in `<li>`). When this function is called (it is called, when an area enclosed by the `<li>` tag is clicked), the anchor tag is given a desired URL in this function which in turn, triggers a click event which causes the same function to be invoked once again - ultimately causing an infinite recursion with the following error.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Is there any way to avoid this recursion, probably by rewriting the function somehow?

The HTML code given here is generated by a UI framework and it is very unlikely to touch it.

I could use `window.location` instead of using `.trigger('click')` but when a user click a sub menu by holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, for example, the page should be opened in a new tab. This does not happen by using `window.location`.

Comment: You could use `$(this).off('click').attr(...).trigger('click')`, but I don't think triggering a click like that will cause the link to be followed.

Answer (score 2):

Trigger the click with javascript it will bypass the handler:

```
$(this).closest("a").attr("href", "www.google.com")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

> This function is called, when a `<span>` inside an `<li>` like as follows is clicked.

No it isn't, and that's the fatal flaw in your code.

```
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu>a", function(event) {
```

Your code is called when the *`<a>`* is clicked, not the `<span>`. And since you're triggering a click on the link, the event handler is called again. And again. And again, until you run out of stack space. Stack overflow!

To fix, just fix your selector: `.subMenu>a>span`

Comment: Thank you. The link does not seem to follow by using either `.attr("href", "URL")[0].click()` or `.attr("href", "URL")[0].trigger('click')`. Does it not follow?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
var a=0;
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu>a", function(event) {
    a++;
    if(a<=1){
    $(this).closest("a").attr("href", "../public_resources/Category.jsf?id=5").trigger('click');
    }else{
        a--;
    }
});
```

If you do not want to involve global variables, you can use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu>a", function(event) {
    if($(this).attr('data-clicked')) return true;
    $(this).closest("a").attr("href", "../public_resources/Category.jsf?id=5").attr('data-clicked',true).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't involve (module-)global variables?

Comment: No need, once it was clicked, it has already had the href changed, no need to change it again. Besides, it will redirect to another page with click

Answer (score 0):

With `.trigger`, you can pass an argument. Try something like this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".subMenu>a", function(event, _ISTRIGGER_) {
    if(_ISTRIGGER_) return;

    $(this).closest("a").attr("href", "../public_resources/Category.jsf?id=5").trigger('click', true);
});
```

But be aware, `.trigger` doesnt active the default behavior. Doing

```
$(this).closest("a").attr("href", "../public_resources/Category.jsf?id=5")[0].click();
```

will active it.

Comment: Thank you. The link does not seem to follow by using either `.attr("href", "URL")[0].click()` or `.attr("href", "URL")[0].trigger('click')`. Does it not follow?